# How to change Service StartType in if statement?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a script that goes through computers.txt and search each server for a service with a particular name (MYSERVICENAME).

```
Get-Content c:\servicelist\computers.txt | % {
    if ($s = Get-Service -Computer $_ -Name MYSERVICENAME* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, StartType
    } else {
        "Service is not available on $_"
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what I could do if I wanted to take the list and of servers that have that name and change their start type to either Manual or Auto (depending on what I specify in the script).

I know I can change the Start Type with something like:

```
Set-Service –Name theservice –Computer thecomputer –StartupType “selectedType”
```

But I wasn't sure if the best way to implement this in the above script.

Comment: As a separate note, be careful as `=` is not the equivalence operator. It sets the value of a variable. In your `If` block if you wanted to compare two variables, you would need to use `-eq`.

Answer (score 2):

The `-ComputerName` parameter of `Get-Service` accepts an array argument, and `Set-Service` can read from the pipeline, so you could simply do something like this:

```
$computers   = Get-Content 'C:\servicelist\computers.txt'
$service     = 'servicename'
$startupType = 'Automatic'

Get-Service -Computer $computers -Name $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Set-Service -StartupType $startupType
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion would be to use **PowerShell Workflows**. I hope this would not be too advanced if you are a beginner. Even if it is, don't be afraid - workflows are easy and powerful. Workflow will execute the same command in parallel and on multiple machines. Simple and easy.

```
workflow Set-ServiceStartType {
    Set-Service -Name MYSERVICENAME -StartupType Manual
}

Set-ServiceStartType -PSComputerName (Get-Content c:\servicelist\computers.txt)
```

If you want to "see" more about that workflow, run following command: `Get-Command Set-ServiceStartType | Select -ExpandProperty ScriptBlock`

For more information see [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/26/powershell-workflows-the-basics/) or [MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows) on powerShell Workflows.

Comment: Thank, I will play with  this.

Answer (score -2):

```
$startupType = 'Manual'  # change to Automatic or Manual for changing Startup Type


get-content c:\servicelist\computers.txt | % {
    if ($s=get-service -computer $_ -name SERVICENAMEHERE* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        $s | select MachineName, ServiceName, StartType | Set-Service -computer $_ -StartupType $startupType
                                                          #Comment above if you don't want to change Startup Type
    }
    else {"Service is not available on $_"}
    }
```

Comment: Do either of you happen to know how I could search for multiple Service names at the same time?  maybe using the -and statement?  I tried adding '-name servicename1 -and servicename2' with no luck.